# GCC Cross Compiler can't pass a void main() test

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I'm building a cross compiler that translates c code into assembly for this processor I'm working with. After several hours of work, I managed to get xgcc.exe to compile so that I can start getting it to spit out actual opcodes. However, I've hit a snag when trying to compile a simple void main code:

```
void main(){}
```

When I run this, I get the following internal compiler error

```
(call_ins 3 2 5 2 (call (mem SI ("__main") [flags 0x41]) [0 S4 A8])

(const_int 0 [0])) test.c:1 -1

(expr_list REG_EH_REGION (const_int 0 [0]) (nil)) (nil))

Internal compiler error: in extract_insn, at recog.c: 2109
```

I've literally copied a machine descriptor file from a working processor similar to mine (moxie) but it still produces the same error. The line that should be collaborating with this error is this:

```
(define_expand "call_value"
  [(set (match_operand:SI 0 "memory_operand" "")
        (call (match_operand:SI 1 "memory_operand" "")
         (match_operand:SI 2 "memory_operand" "")))]
  ""
{
  gcc_assert (MEM_P (operands[1]));
})"
```

But I've changed many parts of it and I've yet to be successful. Any ideas on what is causing this error?

Comment: No clue if this is going to solve your problem, but `main` is supposed to have a return type of `int`, not `void`. Sticking with standard-compliant code might be a good start, at least

Comment: int main simply returns a non-specific segfault within the compiler. Ideally once I get void working, I can figure out how to get int working, but if not even void works, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of hacking around, i resolved the issue with this:

```
(define_expand "call"
  [(call (match_operand:SI 0 "memory_operand" "")
        (match_operand 1 "general_operand" ""))]
  ""
{
  gcc_assert (MEM_P (operands[0]));
})


(define_insn "*call"
  [(call (mem:SI (match_operand:SI
          0 "nonmemory_operand" "i,r"))
     (match_operand 1 "" ""))]
  ""
  "@
   call   %0
   call   %0"
)
```

In a nutshell, it wasn't finding the call instruction because it didn't match up.